# How to get next node using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview

In my html structure, I have table and div tags arranged like this

```
<table>...</table>
<div>...</div>
<table>...</table>
<div>...</div>
<table>...</table>
<div>...</div>
etc...
```

This is the asp.net tree view structure. I want to iterate through all the nodes and sub nodes. (table is the node, the div that appears right after is the sub nodes for that node)

I can iterate through all the table tags by doing this `$('#treeviewid > table')`, which gets me the nodes on that level, but for the current table tag, how can I get the div tag that's right after it, and how can I check if it even exists, because that node might not have any sub nodes.

Thanks.

Comment: `.next('div')` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*how can I get the div tag that's right after it* ?

use `.next()`

```
$('#treeviewid > table').eq(1).next('div');
```

*how can I check if it even exists* ?

use `.length()`

```
if($('#treeviewid > table').eq(1).next('div').length > 0){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with [.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

`$('table')[2].next('div');`

Answer (score 0):

`$('#treeviewid > table').eq(0).next()`

Answer (score 0):

**Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)**

jQuery( "prev + next" )

prev: Any valid selector.
next: A selector to match the element that is next to the first selector.

In subject case:

[$('#treeviewid > table + div')](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: [visit, or see static fixture below:](http://jsfiddle.net/andrevinsky/2ZBEL/7/)

Your markup:

```
<table class="i1">...</table>
<div>1</div>
<table class="i2">...</table>
<!--<div>1</div>-->
<table class="i3">...</table>
<div>3</div>
```

Code to find the div:

```
var divsAfter = $('table.i2').next('div'); // a scenario when the second table is taken
alert(divsAfter.length); // 0, if no 'div' follows
if (divsAfter.length) {
    alert(divsAfter.text());
}
```